# Using environment vars in non-rails cucumber test

Tags: executable, cucumber, webrat

I created a simple smoketest for a portal running java/tomcat/jahia (cms) fronted by cache servers and big ip. Cucumber + Webrat + Mechanize is a good fit for a simple smoketest of this setup. (and it has been very easy to get started).

Right now I have hardcoded into /features/support/paths.rb the following lines:

```
module NavigationHelpers
  #PATH="http://production-environment"
  #PATH="http://staging-environment"
  #PATH="http://test-environment"
  PATH="http://localhost:8080"

  #
  def path_to(page_name)
    case page_name

    when /the homepage/
      "#{PATH}/"
    when [...]
       ...

    end
  end
end

World(NavigationHelpers)
```

Right now I manually switch the comments when I want to test different environments. The issue here is I'd love to **get rid of the constant PATH** and put a default value inside one of the support files. And i also want to be able to feed cucumber with this environment variable from the command line like so:

```
cucumber ENV=staging
```

How do you cope with this issue? Any suggestions? Links to code that deals with this? Snippets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass environment variables to Cucumber like you have done with ENV. Each environment vriable will then be available in Ruby's ENV constant. More details in the [Wiki](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Environment-Variables)

(I just added this page - the feature has been around since 0.3.90 but was only ever mentioned in the History.txt file).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I guess I still need to map something like `ENV=staging` to `http//staging-server/` or similar